# How to understand "relocate objects directly reachable from running code"?

Tags: garbage-collection, llvm

I'm investigating on integrating a gc to my llvm project, and when I read [this document](http://llvm.org/docs/Statepoints.html), one sentence confused me:

> However, for a collector which wishes to relocate objects directly
>   reachable from running code, a higher standard is required.

I don't understand what the move "relocate objects directly reachable from running code" trying to do.

For my information, the concept "relocate" means the gc pointer refereed to a new location of an object, for example:

in Java:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();

foo = new Foo(); // ---> a relocation happens
```

So can anyone explain what the "relocate objects directly reachable from running code" trying to do?

Edit:

About the concept "relocation", the document does not explain it, but I found [this document](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc/blob/master/Documentation/llilc-gc.md), it's a compiler for dotnet which is implement by llvm, it explained this concept:

> A GC algorithm is relocating if during a GC, GC pointers may be
>   updated to refer to the new location of an object. An algorithm update
>   pointers found in certain regions but not others. For instance, GC
>   pointers from the stack might not be updated while GC pointers in the
>   heap might be updatable. If the algorithm relocates pointers from all
>   regions, it is fully relocating. When a GC is relocating pointers from
>   some memory region, it necessarily implies the GC reporting is precise
>   in that region.

I don't know if I understand "relocation" right, so I paste this for you information.

Comment: What you're doing with `foo` is reassignment, not relocation. Relocation is done by the GC and should be invisible to the program. It's not something you trigger by writing certain code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the article is talking about relocating objects in the heap, not from within your code.

There are many different GC algorithms, so let's use HotSpot with G1 as an example.

The heap is divided into two logical regions (generations), young and old.  The young generation is collected cheaply because the Eden space is treated like a stack. When a minor GC occurs, objects are copied from Eden to a survivor space (still in the young generation). This is object relocation, moving it from one part of the heap to another. Objects are also copied from one survivor space to another until the tenuring threshold is reached.  They are then copied to the old generation if still referenced.

For a major GC cycle, objects are relocated within the old generation to reduce fragmentation of the free space.

Objects are accessed via an object header, which contains the address in the heap where the object is currently stored.  During relocation, the object header needs to be updated to ensure it is correct.  To do this safely requires the object header to be locked, thus blocking application threads during the update.  Many GC algorithms group all of these updates together, which leads to the GC pauses that can be visible.

Other algorithms, like C4 in Zing from Azul (who I work for), use a read barrier on the object header to eliminate GC pauses.  If you want more detail you can read the paper, here
http://go.azul.com/continuously-concurrent-compacting-collector

Comment: Does that mean if I access an object, I actually take two moves: first lookup the table for the real address of that object(in case it is moved), then access the real address?

Answer (score 1):

That means to relocate an object whose address is in a function-local variable. Such as this:

```
void doRelevantActions(final Thing t) {
    for(Aspect a : t.getAspects())
        if(a.isRelevant(getCurrentSituation()))
            t.doSomeAction();
}
```

Normally, an `Aspect` is only reachable from a `Thing`. But in that loop, the local variable `a` also reaches an `Aspect` and `a` is probably in a CPU register, so the GC might have to modify the value of a CPU register in order to relocate that `Aspect`.

Modifying the CPU registers of a function while running requires more than a "higher standard", in my opinion. It requires a magic wand.

I believe that the GCs that do this kind of thing do it by ensuring that at some points, there is no state in the CPU registers, so stopping the running thread and modifying all the thread's stack frames is enough to relocate objects. Modifying stack frames is still not exactly a simple chore, though.

**EDIT:** Maybe I misunderstand the core of your question? Maybe you're really wondering what relocation is? Suppose that an object is 100 bytes large, and that at some point, it alone occupies an 8k RAM page, because nothing else on that page is reachable. If the GC can move that 100-byte object to another 8k page, then it can free up 8k. That operation is called relocation.

Comment: Sorry for no humor, does "It requires a magic wand" means changing register is impossible and normal gc do not change register?

Comment: I wouldn't know about impossible. Let's say it's extremely, fantastically, difficult. Normal GC does not change registers, no, it just frees up memory.

Comment: Hi I update my question, honestly speaking I'm not sure I understand the concept "relocation" right, so I paste the explanation for you information.

Comment: It is complicated, and there are details I left out (someone published an ingenious new approach last year). But the gist is: If an object is reachable, but sits in an inconvenient/undesirable block of memory, then the GC can relocate that object and update all pointers to point to the new location. Updating all pointers is difficult in the simplest case, rising towards impossibility in the worst case.